# :Maven build failure for spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

I have been observing the build fail issue for this

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (E:\springcloud\spring-cloud-netflix-master\spring-cloud-netflix-master\spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-contract:jar:2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 2]
```

Comment: Sorry , you will need to provide a lot more information , for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please run `./scripts/build.sh` to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi there, maybe explain what the problem might be, and how this command fixes the problem.